# Slack API - chat.update : "cant_update_message"

Tags: slack-api

I have been trying to update a message from node and getting is error: "cant_update_message", the scopes are set correctly and the bot token is correct. I am also getting the same message in postman. But my company shared me a zap that has the same configuration and is working fine. hope someone can help.

Trying to udpate a message in slack.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're using the same bot token with `chat.update` as you used to post the message you're trying to update? Bot tokens can only edit messages created by your app's bot user.

Comment: I was able to fix it using slack/web-api library with the same creds. am not sure why.